# JQuery How to check the dropdown options selected true or false

Tags: jquery

How can I write this code in jQuery :

```
if (document.getElementById("selectdept_" + ivalnew).options[k].selected == true) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$("#selectdept_" + ivalnew).find("options:eq(" + k + ")").prop('selected', true)
```

`#` is the id selector.

`find()` will get the child elements

`eq()` will get the elements with index.

Answer (score 0):

The object of the selector is first obtained.then selected of the options;
var options=$("#selector option:selected");